# How can I see a list of all variables and their values for one of the run history entries?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to debug a complex LogicApps logic and I need to see the valiables and their values for an instance of a run history.

How can I see a list of all variables and their values for one of the run history entries?

Update #1:
I use run history to track/debug LogicApp runs:

[image]

Within the run history, I can see variables:

[image]

When I have more than 20 variables, inspecting them one at a time could be difficult. Is there any way to see a list of all varaibles and their values in the view above?

If not, what are my options?

Comment: Could you please give me an example to tell me which variables you want to see?

Comment: @FrankGong, thank you for help. I added the updates.